# setfacl: about the options

Tags: linux, bash, acl

what is the difference between this two commands?

```
sudo setfacl -R -m u:www-data:rwx -m u:yourname:rwx app/cache app/logs
sudo setfacl -dR -dm u:www-data:rwx -m u:yourname:rwx app/cache app/logs
```

Javi

Comment: This should be migrated to superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `-d` option the ACLs are applied to the default entry of a folder. These ACLs are applied to newly created files in that folder.

Comment: Thanks! but what is "the default entry of a folder"? Could you give me an example please?

Comment: As far as I know the default entry of a folder is copied to new files you create in this folder.

Comment: mmm..could you give an example?